# Explode multiple columns, keeping column name in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following PySpark dataframe (`first_df`):

| id | cat | dog | bird |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ["persan", "sphynx"] | [] | ["strisores"] |
| 1 | [] | ["bulldog"] | ["columbaves", "gruiformes"] |
| 2 | ["ragdoll"] | ["labrador"] | [] |

And I would like to explode multiple columns at once, keeping the old column names in a new column, such as:

| id | animal | animal_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | persan | cat |
| 0 | sphynx | cat |
| 0 | strisores | bird |
| 1 | bulldog | dog |
| 1 | columbaves | bird |
| 1 | gruiformes | bird |
| 2 | ragdoll | cat |
| 2 | labrador | dog |

So far, my current solution is the following:

```py
animal_types = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=StructType([
    StructField('id', StringType()),
    StructField('animal', StringType()),
    StructField('animal_type', StringType())
]))

for animal_type in animal_types:
  df = first_df \
    .select('id', animal_type) \
    .withColumn('animal', F.explode(animal_type)) \
    .drop(animal_type) \
    .withColumn('animal_type', F.lit(animal_type.upper())) \
    .union(df)
```

But I found it quite inefficient, particularly when working in clusters.

Is there a better spark way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot and explode the array:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'id', 
    'stack(' + str(len(df.columns[1:])) + ', ' + ', '.join(["%s, '%s'" % (col,col) for col in df.columns[1:]]) + ') as (animal, animal_type)'
).withColumn(
    'animal', 
    F.explode('animal')
)

df2.show()
+---+----------+-----------+
| id|    animal|animal_type|
+---+----------+-----------+
|  0| strisores|       bird|
|  0|    persan|        cat|
|  0|    sphynx|        cat|
|  1|columbaves|       bird|
|  1|gruiformes|       bird|
|  1|   bulldog|        dog|
|  2|   ragdoll|        cat|
|  2|  labrador|        dog|
+---+----------+-----------+
```